# Ordering in Spark(Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading from a CSV file and I want only certain fields from the entire CSV my commands are as follows:

```
val readfile = sc.textFile("path").map(m=>m.split(",").filterNot(._startsWith("NA")))    
val required_fields = readfile.map(x=>(x(0),x(1),x(2),x(8),x(15),x(16),x(17)))
```

Now I want to change the type of column 15 from String to Double. So i did this,

```
val myDouble = required_fields.map(x=>(x._1,x._2,x._3,x._8,x._15.toDouble,x._16,x._17))
```

Now i need to take only top 10 values from column 15, so i have used takeOrdered funtion

```
myDouble.takeOrdered(10)(Ordering[Double].on(x=>(-x._5)))
```

But When I run the last command i get ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception 17.

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: can you share some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val readfile = sc.textFile("path").map(m=>m.split(",").filterNot(._startsWith("NA")))    
val required_fields = readfile.map(x=>(x(0),x(1),x(2),x(8),x(15),x(16),x(17)))
```

The second line is equivalent to

```
val required_fields = readfile.map(x=> Tuple7(x(0),x(1),x(2),x(8),x(15),x(16),x(17)))
```

That says, your Tuple has 7 fields.

Your problem is here.

```
myDouble = required_fields.map(x=>(x._1,x._2,x._3,x._8,x._15.toDouble,x._16,x._17))
```

you are expecting tuple fields **_8,_15,_16,_17** which does not exist  on  `Tuple7(...)` that means it got just 7 fields but you are using upto `_17`.I'm wondering, how you did not get any compile time error for `myDouble = required_fields.map(x=>(x._1,x._2,x._3,x._8,x._15.toDouble,x._16,x._17))`